# Why is file output different when called from a loop with a .swp file?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I've been experimenting with the `file` command and I came across something intriguing. When I try to loop all the files of a folder and call the `file` command the output for .swap and .swp files exhibit a weird behaviour. All 3-letter file/folder names in the current folder are printed as valid extensions for the swap file.

`file --extension .test.swp` outputs   `.test.swp: ???` but calling it in a loop has a different output. the difference can be seen below. This seems to happen only if

- There is a for loop
- `file --extension` is used
- There is a .swp/.swap file which is not empty
- There are files/folders with exactly three characters.

```
touch a.txt b c def 123 456
for file in `find . -type f`; do 
    echo $file "->" `file --extension $file` ; 
done
echo "test" > .test.swp
echo "-------------"
for file in `find . -type f`; do 
    echo $file "->" `file --extension $file` ; 
done
```

This prints the output before and after the swap file is added.

```
./def -> ./def: ERROR: (null)
./a.txt -> ./a.txt: ERROR: (null)
./456 -> ./456: ERROR: (null)
./123 -> ./123: ERROR: (null)
./c -> ./c: ERROR: (null)
./b -> ./b: ERROR: (null)
-------------
./def -> ./def: ERROR: (null)
./.test.swp -> ./.test.swp: 123 456 def
./a.txt -> ./a.txt: ERROR: (null)
./456 -> ./456: ERROR: (null)
./123 -> ./123: ERROR: (null)
./c -> ./c: ERROR: (null)
./b -> ./b: ERROR: (null)
```

Can anyone explain this weird behaviour?

EDIT: My Shell is GNU bash, version 3.2.57

Comment: Seems to happen for .sh files too.

Comment: I can't find the `--extension` option in any of the man pages I've checked.

Comment: `file` is not part of bash. It's more important that you tell us what version of `file` you have than what version of bash you have.

Comment: That said, any `*` in the output will be munged (replaced with a list of filenames in the local directory) by the inadequate quoting. **ALWAYS** quote your expansions in shell.

Comment: @Barmar I can find this in my man page `--extension Print a slash-separated list of valid extensions for the file type found.`

`file --version` gives me `file-5.33`

@BlackPearl Yes.

Comment: That is: `echo "$file => $(file --extension "$file")"` is much less error-prone.

Comment: (`for file in $(find . -type f)` and its backtick-using equivalent is also described in [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- not that it's necessarily directly linked to the immediate behavior, but it's a source of unreliability even so).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. I was just curious as to what might have caused the error. I couldn't encounter `*` anywhere and became much more curious by just the 3-letter extensions. File names with any number of characters other than 3 were not printed. Seemed to be a very interesting problem. :)

Comment: ...whereas I'm going to argue that I called it correctly. Sure, it wasn't a `*`, but it was still an unintended glob expansion caused by inadequate quoting.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed, you did call it correctly. Wasn't expecting the '???' to mess up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you didn't quote

```
`file --extension $file`
```

It's returning `???` for `.test.swp`, which is then being processed as a filename wildcard. So your output is the same as if you'd written

```
echo $file "->" ???
```

The wildcard `???` matches all 3-character filenames, so those are shown.

Change to:

```
echo "$file -> `file --extension $file`"
```

You should always quote variables and command substitutions unless you have a good reason not to. See  [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) (it talks about variables, but command substitution works the same way).

Comment: Wow. I overlooked that the '?' can be used as wild cards. Are there any tips to actually debug these kinds of issues? I tired using 'sh -x' flag, but it didn't reveal much.

Comment: @JonSnow, http://shellcheck.net/ (whether using the online or locally-installed versions) will flag this and other unquoted expansions as [SC2046](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, it does. Thank you.